# wordpress migration issue inner pages not working

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress site is working fine on my staging url. When I move it from staging to live url i.e from my subdomain to the root folder, all the inner pages (blogs, shop page etc.) is showing 404 error. However, the home page is showing up correctly.

Following are the steps that I took to move the files from subdomain to root:

1. Copy all the files in the staging folder in cpanel and paste it in the public_html folder.
2. Used this [script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to search and replace the url in the database.

I have checked the db and all the urls have been replaced correctly.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you forgot to clone the database? Just copy pasting the files needed to show pages, doesn't mean the pages will also be copied. Wordpress is a content management system, if you copy the system it won't necessarily copy the content.

Comment: okay, when I moved the files from subdomain to root, the htaccess file was not copied. Now its working fine. Thanks